# Can Import RealmSwift, Can't Instantiate

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I installed RealmSwift using CocoaPods, and am importing RealmSwift without any problems. However, I'm getting a weird error when I'm trying to use it. 
When I do:

```
let realm = try! RealmSwift.Realm()
```

I get this error:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=io.realm Code=0 "Schema validation failed due to the following
>   errors:
>
> - Target type 'RealmSwiftObject' doesn't exist for property 'articles'.
> - Target type 'RealmSwiftObject' doesn't exist for property 'favorites'." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Schema validation
>     failed due to the following errors:
> - Target type 'RealmSwiftObject' doesn't exist for property 'articles'.
> - Target type 'RealmSwiftObject' doesn't exist for property 'favorites'.}:    file
>     /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.1.101.15/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>     line 50

Comment: The errors you mention indicate that there are inconsistencies in how your model classes are declared. Can you please share the declarations so we can see where the errors are?

Comment: What is the try! Doing? Making it non-optional?

Comment: @user2277872 try! means "I know this function call can potentially throw an error but I'm guaranteeing it won't" it's the same concept as using ! to force unwrap an optional or as! To force a cast. The program will crash if the forced operation fails.

Comment: Oh ok. It seemed like a variation of a try block at first. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: The error messages you shared state that your schema is invalid, for whatever reason. So for others to be able to help you, you'll need to share your model definitions since that's what's at fault, not Realm initialization.

Comment: My schema was actually invalid, it runs when I remove my List of Objects in the schema. However, how would I properly declare that?

Comment: Please refer to Realm's documentation on Models to learn how to do that: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models

Answer (score 1):

After `import RealmSwift` in your class.

You can use like this:

```
class FooClass {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    func bar()
    {
        try! realm.write {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually did that - I was playing around with the code, and that's what I copy pasted above. Getting the same error.

Comment: When you're trying, is it open RealmBrowser or something like that?

Comment: Can you try delete app in your simulator or device whatever you use. Then re-install the app. When you changed it your variables of Object class, you need to migrate class or re-install the app. Maybe that might be the problem :/